# Code in onActivityResult() not executed

Tags: java, android

I've got an android application that I want to open a different activity then my main one after a fresh install.

I tried this using startActivityForResult() and SharedPreferences. Here is my code:

main activity:

public class ONTTMainActivity extends Activity {

static final int REQUEST_CODE = 5;

```
@Override    
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
    boolean firstRun = settings.getBoolean("firstRun", true);

    if(firstRun){

        startActivityForResult(
            new Intent(this, ONTTSplashActivity.class), REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

}
```

second activity:

public class ONTTSplashActivity extends Activity {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activityonttsplash);

    final Button btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_skip);
    btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {

            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();       
         }
     });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Toast.makeText(ONTTSplashActivity.this, "Toast Reached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONTT_prefs", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
            editor.commit();
    }
}
```

The problem is that even though the second activity is ended the code in the onActivityResult function is never executed. I tried using a toast to see if it has been reached.

I've seen several similar questions but I've tried every solution but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting `ONTTSplashActivity` from `ONTTMainActivity` for getting result back from ONTTSplashActivity to ONTTMainActivity so    put `onActivityResult` in first `ONTTMainActivity`  activity:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Toast.makeText(ONTTMainActivity .this, "Toast Reached", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONTT_prefs", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("firstRun", false);
            editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OnActivityResult() must be in you first activity not in the second activity.
Since from first activity only you are calling startActivityForResukts() so your first activity expect for results from the second activity.